# jQuery On Selector Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am in the process of migrating my `live()` functions to the `on()` method in jQuery, however I have come across one little issue that I am unsure about and would very much appreciate some advice.

As the jQuery documentation states, this:

```
$('.test').live({
    click: function(){
        alert('.test Clicked')
    }
});
```

Is replaced by this:

```
$(document).on('click','.test',function(){
    alert('.test Clicked')
});
```

**The above is working with no issues (to my knowledge)**. However, if my selector is slightly more specific like the following, I cannot get it to work:

```
$(document).on('click',$('.test',element),function(){
    alert('.test Clicked')
});
```

Is it not possible to place selectors into the second parameter? If not, how can I get around this without assigning an 'id'?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect the line to read:

```
$(element).on('click','.test',function(){
    alert('.test Clicked')
});
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, cannot believe I didn't think of that. Will give it a go and let you know. Thank you :-)

Comment: You LEGEND! Thank you so much, cannot believe I didn't think of that. All sorted! :-D

Answer (score 2):

The on() method only takes text selectors. The whole purpose of the on() method is so you can delegate events so you don't need to provide a selector context. If you wanted to delegate an event to .test inside of element, then you would do this:

```
$(element).on('click','.test',function() {
   alert('.test clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).find(element).on('click','.test',function(){
    alert('.test Clicked')
});
```

document can be removed - but you *should* understand the concept.

```
xxx.subelement.subsubelement
```